How to get, process and build URL with all parameters in javascript?
I have inputs type="text", selects and other elements used for filters. After change any of these i need to refresh page with all url parameters. I need to read all URL parameters, process them and build new URL string for redirect.
In PHP it's easy, something like this:
$domain = 'index.php?';
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $domain .= $key.'='.$value.'&amp;'; // there I can do changes what I need
}
$domain = substr($domain, 0, strlen($domain)-5); // $domain contents full URL with changed parameters

How to do the same in JavaScript?

Why don't you just put these fields into a form with method="get", that you then simply submit? Then it would not need any JavaScript.

I have more parameters in the address, not just the content of the form. But storing them in hidden fields maybe could be the way to do it...

URLSearchParams is your friend

I used URLSearchParams what Daniel A. White advised me in comment and it's work... :)
Code:
let domain = 'index.php?';
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));

params.set('key', 'value'); // there I can change parameter what I need

domain += params.toString(); // domain contents full URL with changed parameters


There's the very useful URL api for this. It has a property that contains the query string key/values.
Let's say you want to add the value name with value "alice" to the current URL. If a name is already set, the new value should overwrite the old:
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
// In the query parameters ("?foo=bar") part of the URL, set a new value.
url.searchParams.set("name", "alice");
// Redirect to the new URL.
window.location = url.toString();

This will take care of adding either a question mark or an ampersand—no need to check that yourself.
Since you're working with PHP, you might encounter a need to not overwrite an existing value, since PHP considers ?tags[]=apple&tags[]=banana an array.
url.searchParams.append("tags[]", "apple");
url.searchParams.append("tags[]", "banana");


As for the reverse, if you wish to populate your form using JavaScript, you can get the values with this API as well:
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
// For singular values:
someTextField.value = url.searchParams.get("name");
// For multiple values:
for (const value of url.searchParams.getAll("tags[]")) {
  // do something with `value`.
}


Thanks, that's also a possible solution.
